# To perform ajax functioning with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Simply, I have an `<a>` tag having values(ID) which will be posted to the same page in clicking,

I wanted to load data into the table based on the ID provided by the post method. On the other hand I am having a clock which is rested again and again when fired a post method.

I simply wanted to do the same via jQuery.

In short I wanted to Implement ajax using jQuery

Also I am using database MySQL, with PHP scripting

Any sort help will be appreciated.

```
<a class="D" href="?ID=<?php echo $rows[0]; ?>" onclick="">Question<?php echo $QNo; ?></a>
```

I wanted the same above and get ID for searching relevant data against the ID.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Here is a good example/explanation of jQuery Ajax with PHP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php

Comment: What are you trying to do. Why is the clock worth mentioning? Why do we need to know about your MySQL db? Have you tried anything at all?

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong here, but you basically want to query a PHP page based on an ID and display relevant content in a div?

To make an AJAX call, setup a PHP page that will query your database and in turn return HTML data which you can then display in a DOM element.

A very simple example of this would be:

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" data-tableId="1" class="linkToLoadTable">Load table 1</a>
<a href="#" data-tableId="2" class="linkToLoadTable">Load table 2</a>
<div id="contentToPopulate"></div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('a.linkToLoadTable').click(function(){
    var pageId = $(this).data('tableId')
    $.ajax({
        url: 'loadTable.php?id='+pageId
    }).done(function(data) {
        $('#contentToPopulate').html(data)
    });
})
```

Comment: first thing I do not wanted to use Ajax I wanted to do the work with jquery and also I wanted to sent some unique ID for "where clause" so that I can fetch via php

and Dear Sir kindly tell me that what is "data-tableId" over here 
is that same data-tableId=tableId

Comment: @ShivamShukla "$.ajax" is a jQuery method to perform a asynchronous  HTTP request. With regards to "data-tableId". It is a data attribute we are using to pass a variable (in this case, an integer). So expanding on the example above. You would need to include something like "$tableRow = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];" in loadTable.php. Then your SQL query would be along the lines of "mysql_query("SELECT name FROM users WHERE id='$tableRow '")"